# How to create a local repository for windows server

Tags: windows, local

How do create a windows local repository in windows OS?
To build a local repo for update the packages for Windows Machine

Comment: what type of repository do you mean?

Comment: Hi @ Smankusors. The repo is for windows package update

Comment: you mean windows update?

Comment: Yes. Is for windows update

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place you asking this question, because Stack Overflow is the place for code programming questions. Your question seems unrelated to programming